# Create function with direct input into lavaan mediation.model in R

Tags: r, lapply, mediator, r-lavaan

In order to run a mediation model using the lavaan package in R, you have to first create a mediation model using this code:

```
mediation.model <- ' 
             # mediator
             mediator ~ a*iv
             dv ~ b*mediator
           
             # direct effect
             dv ~  c*iv

           # indirect effect (a*b)
             ab := a*b

           # total effect
             total := c + (a*b)
         '
```

I am trying to write a function so that I can input specific variables and it'll automatically put them into the model and output the model summary. I have many mediators to test.

This is my current draft of the function, but it doesn't seem to work because the mediation.model part is between parentheses.

```
med <- function(iv, mediator, dv) {
  mediation.model <- ' 
             # mediator
             mediator ~ a*iv
             dv ~ b*mediator
           
             # direct effect
             dv ~  c*iv

           # indirect effect (a*b)
             ab := a*b

           # total effect
             total := c + (a*b)
         '
  fit <- sem(mediation.model, data = df, meanstructure = TRUE,
           se = "boot", bootstrap = 500)

  return(summary(fit, fit.measures=T, standardized=T, ci=TRUE))
}
```

How can I modify this so I can input iv (independent variable), mediator, and dv (dependent variable) and get the output of the entire model? I will eventually need to loop this over several mediators (probably using lapply). I am also open to the input of the function only being the "mediator" and putting in the iv and dv manually if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `paste()` to assemble your model syntax.

```
med <- function(iv, mediator, dv) {
  stopifnot(inherits(iv, "character"))
  stopifnot(inherits(dv, "character"))
  stopifnot(inherits(mediator, "character"))

  mediation.model <- paste0(' 
             # mediator
             mediator ~ a*', iv, '
             ', dv, ' ~ b*', mediator, '
           
             # direct effect
             ', dv, ' ~  c*', iv, '

           # indirect effect (a*b)
             ab := a*b

           # total effect
             total := c + (a*b)
         ')
  fit <- sem(mediation.model, data = df, meanstructure = TRUE,
           se = "boot", bootstrap = 500)

  return(summary(fit, fit.measures=T, standardized=T, ci=TRUE))
}
```

Note that `lavaan`'s `model.syntax` need not be a single `character` string, but can be a `character` vector (e.g., each specified parameter can be 1 element in the vector).